# How to check if nested class element exists

Tags: selenium, xpath, python-3.7

I'm using the Chrome extension XPath Helper on a paywalled bloomberg website.

For example, this would yield the text "Department of the Air Force" from a list of elements with class="stuff ng-binding"

```
(//*[@class="stuff ng-binding"])[1]
```

But when trying to see if this element has the nested class="fa fa-plus-circle", both of these yield "[INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION]" from the xpath helper extension:

```
(//*[@class="stuff ng-binding"])[1][@class="fa fa-plus-circle"]
(//*[@class="stuff ng-binding"])[1]/[@class="fa fa-plus-circle"]
```

What's the xpath to select this nested class?
Thanks

[image]

Edit:
So, what I'm trying to do is to click through an org chart that expands when clicked on. I'm trying to scrape the contents under the DoD.

here's some of my code:

```
done = 0
click_bool = 0
name_xpath = '//*[@class="stuff ng-binding"]'
expand_xpath = '//*[@class="fa fa-plus-circle"]' 
name_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(name_xpath)
        while name_elements:
            for name_element in name_elements:
                if name_element.text == "Department of Defense":
                    click_bool = 1 # only start expanding when it comes across DoD section
                if name_element.text == "Department of the Army":
                    click_bool = 0 # try to keep the scraping within a scope of the org chart list
                    break

                # this should only be active when between DoD and DoA
                if click_bool:
                    try:
                        print(name_element.text) #this prints fine
                        expand_element = name_element.find_element_by_xpath(expand_xpath) # this still tries to click on elements before and after DoA though so I don't this line of trying to find the nested class element works for that specific element
                        expand_element.click()

        done += 1
        name_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(name_xpath) #rescan to see if there's any unopened sections from within DoD
        if done == 2:
            break # if no unopened sections, break
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB yeah you're right, I added my code snippets, thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 0):

You can get it in one line using the xpath axes:

```
name_xpath = '//div[contains(@class,'stuff ng-binding')]/child::i[contains(@class,'fa fa-plus-circle')]'
name_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(name_xpath)
```

Instead of /child you can use others from here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp
Some usefull xpath cheatsheet: https://devhints.io/xpath